# TeXForm without simplification

Tags: simplifying-expressions, latex

I'd like to be able to feed an expression into Mathematica, and have Mathematica convert that expression to TeXForm WITHOUT ANY SIMPLIFICATION WHATSOEVER.

As a trivial example, currently, if I enter

```
6/9 //TeXForm
```

MM returns

```
\frac{2}{3}
```

I'd like to be able to feed it 6/9 and have it return

```
\frac{6}{9}
```

Obviously there are solutions that would effectively involve writing my own parser, but I'm specifically looking for relatively short and clean solutions, if there are any.

Comment: duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61054/convert-mathematica-latex-to-regular-latex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HoldForm` is your friend:

```
6/9 // HoldForm // TeXForm
```

> \frac{6}{9}

Comment: Lovely, thanks!