# How to prevent reduction of a fraction into lowest terms?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, arithmetic

I have a question about the concept of simplification. I want to explain it with an example.
When I write the fraction $4/8$ in Mathematica, the output is

`1/2`.

How can I return this expression as $4/8$? How can I prevent simplifying rational numbers in lowest terms?

Comment: Can't u use "4/8"? ;)

Comment: HoldForm[4/8], and many Examples, if you use the search function on this page.

Comment: ... or `Defer[4/8]`.

Comment: ... or check out `Inactivate`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Since i am a new user of mathematica, i dont know the functions very well. the functions Defer and HoldForm is ok for me. Best regards...

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't find the previous question.

Comment: I just wonder why you'd want to do that

Comment: i am interested in farey sequences. So, i should have the list of farey sequence exactly. When i try to obtain it by mathematica, i could not get the list regularly since mathematica simplifies the fractions. Therefore, i need to unsimplification version of a fraction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TeXForm without simplification](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46790/texform-without-simplification)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the internal function `` Internal`RationalNoReduce ``

```
Internal`RationalNoReduce[4, 8]
```

[image]

```
Internal`RationalNoReduce[4, 8]^2 + 5
```

[image]

Comment: Never seen *that* before. +1