# How to NOT simplify fraction

Tags: evaluation

**How can I prevent Mathematica from simplifying fractions?** What I would like to do is run a test on a list of fractions to see how many are in their reduced form.

For example, I have a list:

```
1/10, 2/10, 5/10
```

I do not want Mathematica to treat it as:

```
1/10, 1/5, 1/2
```

I would like it left exactly as it was originally entered for comparison, i.e. if one list contains 2/10 and the other list contains 1/5 they should be treated as different elements.

I tried converting the elements to strings but Mathematica still simplified the fractions...

**What is the best way to maintain the entire list in the original form?**

Something like:

```
a = {1/10, 2/10, 3/10, 4/10, 5/10};
Internal`RationalNoReduce[Numerator[a], Denominator[a]]
```

still gives

```
Internal`RationalNoReduce[{1, 1, 3, 2, 1}, {10, 5, 10, 5, 2}]
```

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/holdform-does-not-hold-form-for-fractions-sometimes

Comment: See my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69894/how-to-prevent-simplification/69901#69901).

Comment: please see edit

Comment: I reopened the question and posted an answer addressing your stated goal.  Your focus on "an entire list" makes me wonder if you are importing a list of fractions; if this is the case it will be important to import them in a held form, and you will need to describe the external format in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression will be evaluated unless it is entered in a held form, or a form that natively does not evaluate.  For example:

```
a = Hold[1/10, 2/10, 3/10, 4/10, 5/10];

b = {{1,10}, {2,10}, {3,10}, {4,10}, {5,10}};
```

The second representation is a bit easier to work with as the first, which while not evaluating is nevertheless parsed differently from what you might expect:

```
a // FullForm
```

> ```
> Hold[Times[1, Power[10, -1]], Times[2, Power[10, -1]], Times[3, Power[10, -1]], 
>  Times[4, Power[10, -1]], Times[5, Power[10, -1]]]
> ```

Note that every fraction is not parsed as `Rational` but as `Times` and `Power`.

You can work with either format however.  First the easy example (ref: [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)):

```
GCD @@@ b
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 1, 2, 5}
> ```

A GCD of one means that the fraction is in reduced form, while any other value means it is not.  You could for example [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) the fractions that are or are not in reduced form:

```
Select[b, 1 == GCD @@ # &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 10}, {3, 10}}
> ```

To work with the first format you could convert it to the second format with:

```
List @@ (a /. n_*(d_^-1) :> {n, d})
```

> ```
> {{1, 10}, {2, 10}, {3, 10}, {4, 10}, {5, 10}}
> ```

Comment: i think this is what I was looking for, thanks! :D

Comment: @Solarmew Glad I could help. :-)  By the way including in a question what you are actually trying to accomplish is a good idea and in this case necessary to distinguish it from prior questions.

Answer (score 5):

Use HoldForm

```
HoldForm[2/10]
```

$\frac{2}{10}$

```
ReleaseHold[%]

(* Out[68]= 1/5 *)
```

Comment: Tyilo, but that only works for each element. Is there a way to apply it to the entire list without loops?

Comment: @Solarmew yes, the way is to apply `HoldForm` to the entire list `HoldForm[{1/10, 2/10, 5/10}]`