# Give a common denominator to a whole list

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a list, say $\{\frac{1}{36},\frac{1}{36},\frac{1}{18},\frac{1}{18},\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{18},\frac{1}{18},\frac{1}{36},\frac{1}{36}\}$, how can I make it so that all the elements of the list have the same denominator (using the smallest one possible) ?

Comment: The real problem is how to get that numbers `printed`.Mathematica will simplify them on the fly. There are several related question to this on this site. Search for them

Comment: Try multiplying the list by the LCM of the denominators; that will give you the list of numerators.

Comment: `LCM@@Denominator[list]]` might be what you want.

Comment: Related: [How to prevent simplification?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69894/14303), [How to NOT simplify fraction](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71486/14303).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l = {1/36, 1/36, 1/18, 1/12, 1/18};
lcm = LCM @@ (Denominator@l);
ToString[#]/lcm & /@ (l lcm);
```

Answer (score 5):

If it is **only for printing** you could do something like this

```
list = {1/36, 1/36, 1/18, 1/12, 1/18};

max = Max@Denominator@list;
p1 = ToString /@ max/Denominator@list;
p2 = Array[ToString@max &, Length@list;

Column[#, Center, Spacings -> 1, Dividers -> Center] & /@ Transpose[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Not only for printing**. One more option is to use `HoldForm[]` (or `Defer[]` suggested by J.M.):

```
Clear[list, den, print];    
list = {1/36, 1/36, 1/18, 1/12, 1/18};
```

HoldForm:

```
den = Denominator@list;
print = HoldForm /@ (Max[den]/den)/Max[den]
```

To evaluate the expression:

```
ReleaseHold@print
```

PS. One may olso use `Inactivate[]`

Comment: I would prefer `Defer[]` (or `Inactivate[]` in newer versions) myself.

Comment: @J.M. Why? Is it seriuos difference? I've just put it to avoid `ToString` solution.