# How to not simplify fractions generated by functions?

Tags: functions

Let's say I have a function $f[x]=[2/x]$

How can I do something like $2f[4]/4$ result in $4/16$, and not $1/4$ or $2/8$?

Answer (score 4):

Related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69894/58370).

```
f[x_] := Internal`RationalNoReduce[2, x];
f[4]*Internal`RationalNoReduce[2, 4]

(* 4/16 *)
```